# Azure DevOps Pipelines "Waiting for console output from an agent..."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I require something from the output of a running release task in order for it to complete (an authenticate code).  But the console is now not updating. All I get is "Waiting for console output from an agent..."

[image]

This happens on both our self-hosted agents (Linux or Windows) and on the Hosted Ubuntu 1604 agent.

The step in question is the standard Kubernetes task: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/KubernetesV1

This was not always happening.

Comment: I am also getting same issue :(

Comment: Same issue, I leave it for a day, then it comes back and nothing releases

Comment: Still no solution about the issue ? I also get the same error but no solution was reported

Comment: All of a sudden I am seeing the similar error. Not sure whats going on

Answer (score 1):

To rule out the possibility of `kubectl` awaiting console input (as has been discussed above), you could try

`kubectl apply --dry-run=client [other args]`

or

`kubectl apply --dry-run=server [other args]`

This could give you guidance as to how to proceed, perhaps with `--force` or `--overwrite` flags if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. After troubleshooting and canceling the task, I noticed that the agent was waiting for a response from the user.

In my case, I was trying to unzip a file where the destination folder already exists with content. So the system was asking the user to replace the destination folder content that's why the agent was waiting.

```
2020-03-23T04:14:57.8941954Z unzip /home/azure-deploy-test/AutoEcole.zip -d /home/test-deployment/
2020-03-23T04:14:57.9086229Z Archive:  /home/azure-deploy-test/AutoEcole.zip
2020-03-23T04:14:57.9087639Z 
2020-03-23T04:14:57.9136932Z ##[error]replace /home/test-deployment/AutoEcole? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: 
2020-03-23T04:53:12.1979529Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
```

Answer (score -3):

This was an issue with Microsoft's Azure DevOps Services that has been acknowledged and rectified by Microsoft.
This issue was reported as an issue with the "Liveness in Release Management UI".

All you have to do is access your project using the below URL:-

https://dev.azure.com/{your organization}/{your project}.

This is an official solution provided by Microsoft. This resolved the issue for me.

Please share more details in the comments section if you still face the issue.

Comment: I am seeing this behavior in Jan 2020 :( I tried using both old and new urls.

Comment: Yes, me too - this is not fully resolved by MS (of course)